# Is it possible to use multiple foldmarkers in vim?

Tags: vim, folding

I'm coding C# in Vim and I want to be able to fold both

```
+---- 3 lines: void SomeFunction()-----------------------------------------------
```

As well as

```
+---- 42 lines: #region The Answer To Life---------------------------------------
```

However, foldmarker must be a literal string. I've been led to the idea of `foldmethod=syntax`, but this doesn't work out of the box in Vim 7.3.

Other than setting the fold method to manual and writing a script, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Would [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fold_a_C_sharp_region) help?

Comment: `but this doesn't work out of the box in Vim 7.3.` what do you mean about this? If you can fold text, you compiled your vim with `+folding`. You can use  `foldmethod=syntax`

Comment: with `foldmethod=syntax`, when I get inside `{ }` and hit `zc` to close the fold, it doesn't close anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Vim 7.3 runtime has a `syntax/cs.vim` file (from 14-Aug-2009) that supports syntax folding for `#region`. Syntax folding is nice; I'd advise against another foldmethod. I would contact the author of the syntax file and suggest the missing folding of functions as an enhancement; many other filetypes have this, and it seems to be common and helpful. (This can be made configurable for those who don't want one or the other.)

In the meantime, you can add the following to `~/.vim/after/syntax/cs.vim` to enable folding of any curly braces blocks:

```
syn region csFold start="{" end="}" transparent fold
```

Comment: Thank you - works great! This should have been the accepted answer!

Comment: This still works for me